# Template error for Fn::GetAtt in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am getting "Template error: every Fn::GetAtt object requires two non-empty parameters, the resource name and the resource attribute" when my pipeline runs in AWS.
I am trying to create Output (via Output section) for an S3 web-site URL.

My CFN script is below.

```
Resources:
  MyS3BucketName:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    AccessControl: PublicRead
    WebsiteConfiguration:
      IndexDocument: index.html
    BucketName:
      !Sub
      - '${TheEnv}-sample-s3-ui-${TheBucketRegion}'
      - TheEnv: !Ref EnvName
        TheBucketRegion: !Ref AWS::Region
    BucketEncryption:
      ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
        - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
            KMSMasterKeyID: !GetAtt S3BucketKmsKey.Arn
            SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms
    PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
      BlockPublicAcls: true
      BlockPublicPolicy: true
      IgnorePublicAcls: true
      RestrictPublicBuckets: true
    LifecycleConfiguration:
      Rules:
        - Id: expiration-rule
          Status: Enabled
          ExpirationInDays: !Ref S3BucketFileExpirationInDays
    VersioningConfiguration:
      Status: Suspended

S3BucketForIncomingFilesBucketPolicy:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    Bucket: !Ref MyS3BucketName
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Sid: "FullAccessForOps"
          Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            AWS:
              - !Sub
                - "arn:aws:iam::${TheAccountNumber}:role/${TheRoleName}"
                - TheAccountNumber: !FindInMap [AccountNumbers, ops, core]
                  TheRoleName: "Ops"
            - !Sub
              - "arn:aws:iam::${TheAccountNumber}:role/${TheRoleName}"
              - TheAccountNumber: !FindInMap [AccountNumbers, devops, core]
                TheRoleName: "Developer"
        Action:
          - "s3:*"
        Resource:
          - !Join ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", !Ref MyS3BucketName]]
          - !Join ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", !Ref MyS3BucketName, "/*"]]
      - Sid: "FullAccessToAccountRoot"
        Effect: "Allow"
        Principal:
          AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root'
        Action:
          - "s3:*"
        Resource:
          - !Join ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", !Ref MyS3BucketName]]
          - !Join ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", !Ref MyS3BucketName, "/*"]]

Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
  Value: !GetAtt MyS3BucketName.Arn
  Description: URL for website hosted on S3
S3BucketSecureURL:
  Value: !Join
    - ''
    - - 'https://'
      - !GetAtt
      - MyS3BucketName
      - DomainName
  Description: Name of S3 bucket to hold website content
```

I got this example from AWS [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-s3.html)

Not sure what's wrong here.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: No, the document on the page you linked is different. Pay attention to the last section (`S3BucketSecureURL.value`) and the indentation. Template in AWS docs passes a 2-element list to `GetAtt`. You pass nothing to `GetAtt` and try to join everything together. Their doc is equivalent to `- !GetAtt: [MyS3BucketName, DomainName]` - it's a long form of `GetAtt` spelling.

Answer (score 0):

You have to indent your arguments to `GetAtt`:

```
S3BucketSecureURL:
  Value: !Join
    - ''
    - - 'https://'
      - !GetAtt
        - MyS3BucketName
        - DomainName
```

or

```
S3BucketSecureURL:
  Value: !Join
    - ''
    - - 'https://'
      - !GetAtt MyS3BucketName.DomainName
```